# ArcGIS Server 10.0 Java - Upgrading JAI

Tags: arcgis-server, java, jvm

I am developing a SOE for ArcGIS Server 10 SP 5 in Java.  The SOE makes use of some GeoTools functionality - specifically the HeatmapProcess.

I have written a small api (with all GeoTools, no ArcObjects) and packaged it as a standalone jar.  The standalone jar works perfect in projects outside of ArcGIS Server.  However, when used inside the SOE, I am eventually get hit with a "Provider com.sun.media.jai.imageioimpl.ImageReadWriteSpi not found" error message.

I am traditionally a .NET guy, so Java's class loading mechanisms are a little alien to me.  I am fairly confident I have the class-path of my SOE set properly - as all other GeoTools classes instantiate just fine.  Looking at the ESRI install, I can see that some version of JAI is included in the java/lib/shared directory - but it is an older version than what I have included in the class-path of my SOE.

Again admitting my lack of knowledge about all things Java to include the JVM, I am assuming that the version of JAI shipped with ArcGIS Server is taking precedence over the version I have included in the class-path of my SOE - through how ArcGIS Server starts the JVM.

So I have a couple of questions for you Java guru's out there:

1. Is there some way I can update the version of JAI loaded by ArcGIS Server?
2. Is there some way I can make ArcGIS Server start the JVM giving precedence to the class-path I define?

Comment: Which OS you have?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2